# Generate one bar graph per row and align bars in grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame listing individuals with several variables that all add up to 1.

```
head(data)
      name         var1        var2       var3       var4      var5        var6
1 Individual1 0.00000000 0.16306533 0.000000000 0.08793970 0.000000000  0.7489950
2 Individual2 0.13739632 0.03606203 0.000000000 0.02740714 0.000000000  0.7991345
3 Individual3 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.03278689 0.000000000  0.9672131
4 Individual4 0.09302326 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.02325581 0.000000000  0.8837209
5 Individual5 0.16761169 0.09765373 0.004633884 0.06131587 0.003519406  0.6652654
6 Individual6 0.14689943 0.25081479 0.008559214 0.05957384 0.003552058  0.5306007
```

I would like to use an horizontal stacked bar plot to display the distribution of these variables for each row. For instance for one individual :

```
data <- data %>% melt()

data %>% filter(name=="Individual1") %>%
ggplot(aes(name, value,  fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FDD835", "#039BE5", "#5C6BC0", "#FF5722", "#66BB6A", "#000000"))
```

I'd like to generate one graph for each row and display some of them in a grid with 2 columns, the name of the individual at the top of the bar and the legend at the bottom of the grid

For the grid part, I've tried to use `gridExtra`but since the name is displayed at the left of the graph, the bars are not aligned.

EDIT : reproducible example made by dc37 :

```
structure(list(name = c("Individual1", "Individual2", "Individual3", 
"Individual4", "Individual5", "Individual6"), var1 = c(0, 0.13739632, 
0, 0.09302326, 0.16761169, 0.14689943), var2 = c(0.16306533, 
0.03606203, 0, 0, 0.09765373, 0.25081479), var3 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.004633884, 0.008559214), var4 = c(0.0879397, 0.02740714, 
0.03278689, 0.02325581, 0.06131587, 0.05957384), var5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.003519406, 0.003552058), var6 = c(0.748995, 0.7991345, 
0.9672131, 0.8837209, 0.6652654, 0.5306007)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x562d71683610>)
```

Comment: Running the dput function on your data and pasting it here makes it easier for people to mess around with it.

Comment: Duly noted for my next questions! dc37 has done the work for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `facet_rep_wrap` function from the package `lemon` to organise one plot for each individual organized in a two column and with the name at the top:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lemon)
df %>% pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = val, fill = var))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FDD835", "#039BE5", "#5C6BC0", "#FF5722", "#66BB6A", "#000000"))+
  facet_rep_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y", ncol = 2, repeat.tick.labels = FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to get ?

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(name = c("Individual1", "Individual2", "Individual3", 
"Individual4", "Individual5", "Individual6"), var1 = c(0, 0.13739632, 
0, 0.09302326, 0.16761169, 0.14689943), var2 = c(0.16306533, 
0.03606203, 0, 0, 0.09765373, 0.25081479), var3 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.004633884, 0.008559214), var4 = c(0.0879397, 0.02740714, 
0.03278689, 0.02325581, 0.06131587, 0.05957384), var5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.003519406, 0.003552058), var6 = c(0.748995, 0.7991345, 
0.9672131, 0.8837209, 0.6652654, 0.5306007)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x562d71683610>)
```

Comment: This is great thanks! Would it be possible to order the different values for each graph, so that the biggest value for Individual1 would be first in the bar graph, then the second biggest second, etc., and the same for each individual?

Comment: You're welcome ;) Regarding your question, right now, I do not see a quick way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe you can post a question regarding this issue.